# Is there any way not using JSON or XML after ajax response and implement PHP variable directly?

Tags: php, ajax, parsing

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cau");
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM third");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $values =  $row['website'];
}
```

I am getting the values from an `ajax` request. Is there a way not using `JSON` or `XML` after that part? I mean can I use `$values` as `<?php echo $values ?>` in my another page?

**example:**

```
//get some pure PHP data = XHR.responseText
<select>
    <option><?php echo $values ?></option>
<select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get the results `$values` as JSON, then all you will have to do is write this line:

```
$values = json_decode($data, true);
```

and the $values is now a PHP array.

As for using the same `$values` results in another area of your site you will need to store it in some sort of registry so that you can retrieve it across scripts.

Comment: which page should i do this?database call page or ajax call page and what is $data?

Comment: The above is in the front end. So you made the call, db picked records up and now AJAX is sending the data back to the client. $data is what you receive from your AJAX call. You can then transform the response to an array and use that in your current view or store it somewhere else for use throughout the application

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send the response to your php script using get or post, and as Nikolaos said you should decode your json string